# Is there a setting I can change in 2.8 that will prevent system lockup when attempting cycles rendering with an unsupported graphics card?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hardware

I have a Radeon 7000 series graphics card, on Linux Mint 18. AMD does not support their driver anymore (as far as I can tell based on old forum posts) and I can only use the open source driver for the AMD card.

But the AMD with the open source drivers works great. I have three monitors and the whole system is supper stable. I have no problems with any other programs, and can even run Blender 2.8 for hours with no issues.

Unless I, in the default scene:

1. Enable Cycles rendering
2. Create a rendered view port.
3. Change the default light to a spotlight and start playing with settings, like the direction it's pointing, color, etc.

It will lock up the entire computer requiring a hard reset 100% of the time, within 5 to 20 seconds. It does actually start to render before crashing.

So I don't know if this is a bug, but I suspect it may be a hardware/driver/Blender incompatibility issue.

The question is, can I disable GPU rendering (if that's the issue)? Or tick some other setting to make cycles rendering stable on the hardware I have (even if it's slower)?

**Update**: I've also been able to freeze the computer consistently when trying to attach and/or pose an armature attached to a model with about 125k vertices. (I don't know if that's considered high poly or not, but it says the model uses 105 MB of ram and I have 8 GB.)

I'm not sure if this is related and the graphics card is the problem? I don't want to spring for an expensive card unless I know for sure, especially since getting multi-monitor on Linux is very hit and miss with open source drivers. Are proprietary graphics card drivers required for proper Blender functionality on Linux? Or can you use advanced things like cycles and Meshroom with the FOSS drivers?